# DB script execution to create tables on MySQL DB fails in WSO2 APIM 3.1.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I followed the steps given in WSO2 documentation (https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/setting-up-databases/changing-default-databases/changing-to-mysql/) to change the default DB to MySQL.

I created the databases "wso2am_db" and "wso2shared_db" in MySQL and granted the user "wso2carbon" ALL access on both these DB's.

Now, while trying to execute the script as given in the documentation to create tables in wso2shared_db, I am getting a syntax error as shown below. Am I going wrong somewhere?

[image]

Comment: What is your mysql version?

Comment: Hi Pubci, It is 8.0.

Comment: log to the DB server and user the source command to create tables of the script. Then you may see where the fail the script.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this format to run the script?
`mysql -h "server-name" -u "your_username" -p "your_password" "database-name" < "filename.sql"`